# What is the meaning of word завцеха?

Tags: значения

What is the meaning of word завцеха? I encountered in Vysockij's song Dialog u televizora and most attempts to search for the word on the web lead to this song:

```
Ой, Вань, умру от акробатиков!
Смотри, как вертится, нахал!
Завцеха наш товарищ Са́тюков
Недавно в клубе так скакал.
```

Was it her boss from the factory who was dancing in such a way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Зав - сокращение от заведующий.

Завцеха - заведующий цехом.  Неправильный падеж (правильно "завцехом") - следствие низкого образовательного уровня персонажа.  Слово "завцеха" образовано по образцу "замдиректора" (заместитель директора).

Цех - "производственное помещение или отдельное сооружение, оснащённое станками, другим оборудованием; производственное подразделение заводов и фабрик, выполняющее определённую функцию или выпускающее определённую категорию продукции, реже — небольшое самостоятельное производственное предприятие."

So, завцеха is a head of a factory department.  In this case, it is a "fifth sewing factory" where Zina works.  In most cases, this position at garment factory is called начальник цеха, but заведующий цехом is also used occasionally.

Comment: Actually, from the lyrics of the song I understand that she is sewing clothes in the factory. "На нашей пятой швейной фабрике
Такое вряд ли кто пошьёт."

Comment: @VladimirF - you are right, I'll fix it.